Downloading Images from private storage bucket using Glide in Android
I am using Glide in my Android Kotlin app. I have a Storage bucket on Google Cloud storage where I have stored all of my images which are private and can be only accessed with my custom endpoint.
As far as I have used Glide, I were only able to download the images from a public URL,
Now how can I use Glide to download images from a private storage bucket or is there any other way to do that?

Use Volley or Retrofit to download the image from your private storage bucket then pass that downloaded file path to glide like Glide.with(context)     .load(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "image1.jpg"))  // Use local file path     .into(imageView1);
